# WCF: how to choose which type an interface will be serialize into?

Tags: wcf, serialization, .net-4.0

When using WCF,
how can you choose which type an interface will be serialized into?
for example, the `CarA` type is used in the server, and they are sent to client over WCF as `ICar`s, and the client should receive them as `CarB`s.

```
public interface ICar
{
   int Size { get; set; }
   int Price { get; set; }
}

public class CarA : ICar
{
   //ICar implementations...
}

public class CarB : ICar
{
   //ICar implementations...
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ICarManager
{
   [OperationContract]
   ICar GetMyCar(int userID);
}
```

Comment: *"which type an interface will be serialized into"* - this makes zero sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"which type an interface will be serialized into"* - this makes zero sense. If you send CarA's to your client the client will receive CarA's.

I think you *may* be asking about how to tell WCF that your service contract contains types which are derived from another type. To do this you can use [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx).

**UPDATE**

If you want to return a type of ICar in your service operation you need to specify the concrete types which will be available on your endpoint. You do this by using the `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute` like so:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CarA))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CarB))] 
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICarManager
{
   [OperationContract]
   ICar GetMyCar(int userID);
}
```

Comment: I need to use ICars as CarBs in the client side because CarB has UI-specific code in it. do I need to create new Instances of CarB from received ICars?

Comment: You need to send an instance of type CarB back to the client that needs an instance of type CarB

Comment: Okay. I thought I could somehow send CarA's and receive them as CarB's. guess I'll have to create new CarB instances from CarAs on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at customize reply message by implement custom extension using `IDispatchMessageFormatter`

try this link if help you 
[IDispatchMessageFormatter – How to customize reply Messages on the server side](http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/idispatchmessageformatter/)

Answer (score 1):

From Your server side you can only expose [unique endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx) so you will expose only one endpoint as `ICar` and then you will choose which implementation of ICar you want to host via [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) ,it can be `CarA` or `CarB`.

Now on client side you will just have a only interface as `ICar` and you should  not be confused with which type should be serialized using your interface `Icar`. You will be only calling server side to get the service not the implementation.

More on ServiceHost

> Use the ServiceHost class to **configure and expose a service for use by
>   client applications** when you are not using Internet Information
>   Services (IIS) or Windows Activation Services (WAS) to expose a
>   service. Both IIS and WAS interact with a ServiceHost object on your
>   behalf